# How to reorder day of year so that seasons line up

Tags: r, time, dplyr, lubridate

I am working with seasonal data in Australia that spans from their Spring to Fall. I would like to have a column with day of year. However, when I use the `yday` function from the `lubridate`, I receive a distribution like this:

[image]

The issue here is that the Australian summer (peak time for data collection) goes through the new year. If I tried to add this variable into the model, it would produce incorrect results.

So my question is:

**How can I get a seasonally appropriate 'day of year' column for this dataset**

I have included some data here:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(11323, 11323, 11323, 11323, 
12784, 11324, 12785, 11324, 12419, 12785, 12786, 12786, 13151, 
13151, 13151, 12787, 12421, 15343, 15709, 12787, 14614, 15344, 
11327, 15344, 14614, 13154, 15711, 15711, 11328, 13154, 16442, 
15712, 15712, 16442, 16442, 13886, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 
16444, 16444, 13887, 13157, 13157, 13158, 13158, 11697, 16445, 
13158, 13889, 16446, 11698, 15716, 11333, 16447, 13525, 13525, 
13160, 15351, 11335, 12430, 14257, 13161, 12796, 13162, 12066, 
13162, 13892, 13162, 13893, 16085, 14989, 16815, 16085, 16086, 
13164, 16086, 17182, 13894, 17183, 15356, 17183, 13165, 11704, 
14992, 13166, 14262, 17184, 12435, 11706, 17185, 14628, 14993, 
14628, 14629, 14629, 14994, 13168, 16455, 16456, 12804, 16456, 
16456, 13899, 12805, 14996, 14996, 16822, 16457, 13171, 16458, 
14997, 12806, 14997, 14998, 13172, 13172, 13172, 14998, 13173, 
13173, 12808, 12808, 13173, 17192, 13904, 13174, 13174, 13174, 
14271, 13175, 13175, 15001, 17193, 12445, 17194, 13176, 12445, 
14272, 16464, 16464, 15734, 13907, 14638, 14639, 13178, 13178, 
16465, 14639, 16466, 13179, 13179, 16101, 13179, 13910, 12449, 
16467, 13910, 16467, 13181, 15372, 13181, 14277, 16468, 14278, 
13182, 14278, 12451, 16469, 16470, 13183, 14279, 16835, 14644, 
15010, 13549, 14645, 12819, 12819, 17203, 17203, 12454, 12820, 
17203, 12821, 15012, 13916, 13916, 12821, 13917, 15013, 15013, 
13187, 13917, 13918, 13553, 17206, 14284, 12457, 16476, 14285, 
15380, 14285, 16476, 12825, 12459, 12459, 13920, 16477, 13921, 
12460, 16478, 12460, 14287, 16114, 14288, 16844, 11731, 16479, 
16480, 11367, 11367, 11367, 16845, 16481, 16481, 16846, 16846, 
12829, 12830, 11003, 16482, 13925, 11369, 12465, 16483, 16483, 
16483, 14657, 17215, 11371, 14658, 16484, 16484, 17216, 16485, 
12467, 16850, 11737, 14295, 12834, 12468, 14295, 16851, 13200, 
13200, 16487, 11374, 15026, 11375, 16488, 16488, 12836, 16488, 
11376, 14663, 13202, 14663, 14663, 14664, 11742, 15029, 11377, 
13203, 16491, 16491, 16491, 13569, 13204, 13205, 14301, 11744, 
16492, 13935, 16493, 11380, 16493, 11014, 13936, 16494, 13937, 
13937, 13572, 16494, 13208, 11382, 13938, 11016, 13208, 11748, 
14670, 16496, 14670, 14670, 11384, 14671, 14306, 14671, 12479, 
14672, 16498, 16498, 14672, 14672, 14673, 13942, 12481, 13942, 
12481, 14309, 16500, 12482, 13943, 13943, 12849, 12483, 15771, 
13944, 16501, 16867, 16502, 13945, 12484, 15406, 17234, 16868, 
11024, 16503, 17234, 17235, 17235, 17235, 17235, 16869, 17236, 
13948, 13948, 13948, 17236, 15045, 15410, 13949, 16141, 13219, 
15046, 12489, 15411, 13950, 13950, 11395, 11395, 11395, 12856, 
11395, 15779, 15048, 16874, 12857, 16874, 16875, 16510, 16510, 
15049, 15049, 14685, 12859, 16511, 15050, 16146, 16512, 14686, 
12860, 12860, 12860, 16513, 16878, 14322, 12861, 11400, 15784, 
16514, 15784, 13227, 12862, 16515, 12497, 16515, 16515, 14689, 
13594, 14690, 12498, 12864, 12864, 11404, 13595, 11404, 12865, 
12499, 12500, 12866, 14327, 16518, 16518, 14693, 14328, 14693, 
16519, 16519, 12502, 16520, 14329, 14329, 14329, 12503, 11042, 
16521, 11042, 13234, 11409, 12504, 14331, 12504, 12504, 15427, 
15427, 13601, 15427, 11775, 13602, 16889, 17255, 12506, 12506, 
16160, 12873, 15429, 14334, 12507, 12508, 12508, 11047, 13969, 
12508, 13970, 11414, 14336, 13605, 13970, 12876, 17259, 16893, 
16163, 13606, 13972, 16894, 16894, 11416, 13607, 13973, 12878, 
13243, 11417, 13973, 17262, 12513, 13974, 12513, 12513, 16897, 
12514, 12514, 16897, 11419, 13976, 16898, 16898, 13976, 16898, 
16169, 12151, 15804, 11421, 16899, 16170, 16535, 12883, 16170, 
16535, 11057, 11057, 16171, 13979, 16171, 13980, 13250, 14711, 
16537, 13980, 14712, 13981, 15808, 13981, 14712, 14713, 14713, 
14713, 16174, 14713, 16905, 15444, 16905, 14349, 14349, 13619, 
14715, 12523, 16906, 14350, 14716, 13620, 15446, 12524, 12524, 
13621, 13621, 13621, 14352, 12525, 12526, 12526, 12526, 12526, 
14718, 12527, 11066, 16910, 12527, 13623, 16911, 12528, 16911, 
14720, 16911, 14721, 12529, 13990, 11068, 13990, 14357, 12530, 
14722, 14357, 13626, 13627, 12531, 13627, 13992, 13992, 11071, 
13993, 11071, 11071, 14359, 13994, 11072, 13994, 14360, 13994, 
14361, 11073, 14361, 14361, 14361, 16188, 16188, 14362, 14362, 
14362, 11075, 13997, 14363, 14363, 14363, 14364, 16190, 14364, 
16190, 16190, 14365, 16191, 16191, 11808, 16191, 14366, 14366, 
16192, 11078, 14366, 16193, 16193, 16193, 16193, 16193, 16194, 
16194, 16194, 16194, 16194, 12542, 16195, 16195, 12542, 12542, 
12543, 12543, 12543, 12543, 16196, 14005, 14371, 16197, 14005, 
14005, 12545, 14006, 12545, 14006, 12545, 14007, 14007, 12546, 
12546, 12546, 14739, 14008, 12547, 12547, 14008, 14009, 14009, 
14740, 12548, 15470, 14741, 14741, 15471, 14741, 14741, 14742, 
14742, 14742, 16203, 14742, 14743, 14743, 14743, 14743, 14743, 
16205, 16205, 13283, 16205, 16205, 16206, 13284, 13284, 16206, 
13284, 16207, 16207, 16207, 16207, 15476, 15477, 15477, 15477, 
15477, 15477, 15478, 15478, 15478, 14748, 15478, 15479, 14749, 
11827, 14749, 14749, 11828, 11828, 14750, 11828, 14750, 16943, 
16943, 16943, 16943, 16943, 11100, 11100, 11100, 11100, 11100, 
16945, 16945, 16945, 16945, 16945, 16946, 16946, 16946, 16946, 
16946, 16947, 16947, 16947, 16947, 16947, 16948, 16948, 16948, 
16948, 16948, 16949, 16949, 16949, 16949, 16949, 16314, 16314, 
14853, 16314, 16314, 16315, 16315, 14489, 14489, 14489, 16316, 
16316, 16316, 14855, 14490, 16317, 13760, 16317, 16317, 16317, 
16318, 16318, 13761, 14126, 13761, 13762, 15223, 13762, 16319, 
16319, 12667, 14859, 14859, 17050, 12667, 16321, 11207, 11207, 
11207, 11207, 11208, 11208, 14496, 13400, 13400, 16323, 14497, 
16323, 13401, 14497, 14498, 16324, 14498, 16324, 13402, 16325, 
15229, 11211, 15229, 13403, 15230, 15230, 15961, 17056, 15230, 
14866, 15231, 13040, 15231, 15962, 13771, 14867, 14502, 15963, 
11580, 14868, 14868, 15233, 16694, 16694, 15965, 14869, 15965, 
13043, 14504, 14139, 16696, 12678, 14505, 15966, 14871, 13045, 
16697, 16697, 14140, 14872, 11219, 11219, 14872, 13411, 13412, 
11220, 15969, 14873, 14873, 14509, 14874, 14509, 14874, 12682, 
14875, 12683, 14875, 14875, 14875, 12684, 11223, 14511, 14511, 
14876, 14877, 12685, 14877, 14877, 12685, 12686, 16339, 14878, 
14147, 14878, 16340, 14879, 14879, 14879, 14879, 11227, 11227, 
14880, 14880, 14880, 14881, 14881, 16342, 14881, 14881, 16343, 
14882, 14882, 14882, 14882, 11230, 14883, 12691, 14883, 12691, 
16345, 14153, 16710, 14884, 14884, 14154, 15615, 14885, 12693, 
11232, 14886, 14155, 14155, 14886, 14886, 14887, 14887, 14887, 
14887, 14887, 14888, 14888, 14888, 12696, 14523, 14889, 16350, 
14889, 15619, 14889, 14890, 14525, 14890, 14525, 14525, 14526, 
14891, 14891, 14891, 14526, 14892, 14892, 16353, 16353, 12335, 
14893, 14893, 14893, 14893, 14893, 13798, 17085, 14894, 17085, 
13068, 14895, 13069, 14895, 14895, 14895, 17087, 14896, 17087, 
14896, 12339, 17088, 16358, 16358, 14532, 16358, 14898, 12706, 
14898, 14898, 14898, 16360, 14899, 14899, 11246, 14899, 14900, 
12708, 14900, 14900, 14900, 14901, 14901, 14901, 16362, 14901, 
14902, 14902, 14902, 14537, 14902, 14903, 14903, 14903, 14903, 
12711, 14904, 12712, 14904, 12712, 14904, 15635, 14905, 11252, 
14905, 11252, 14906, 14906, 12349, 14906, 14906, 14542, 14907, 
14542, 14542, 16368, 16369, 14908, 14908, 14177, 16369, 16370, 
14909, 14909, 12352, 16370, 14910, 17101, 14910, 14545, 14910, 
14911, 11258, 16737, 12719, 14911, 16373, 16373, 14912, 14912, 
12720, 14913, 14913, 14913, 14913, 11260, 14914, 16375, 11992, 
11627, 14914, 14915, 14915, 14915, 14550, 15280, 14916, 13820, 
14551, 14916, 14916, 14917, 14917, 14917, 14917, 14917, 11265, 
14553, 16014, 14918, 12726, 11266, 14919, 11266, 16380, 14919, 
14920, 12728, 12363, 12363, 14920, 14921, 14921, 17112, 14921, 
14921, 14922, 14922, 14922, 11269, 14922, 14923, 14923, 14923, 
16384, 14923, 14924, 16385, 14924, 14924, 11271, 16386, 14194, 
14925, 16386, 14925, 14926, 16387, 13465, 14926, 11273, 11640, 
12005, 14196, 14927, 14196, 14197, 12736, 14928, 14928, 14928, 
12737, 13833, 14929, 14929, 11642, 14930, 14930, 14930, 14930, 
14930, 17122, 12739, 13470, 13470, 12374, 14932, 12375, 14932, 
13471, 13471, 11280, 14933, 14933, 14933, 14202, 14934, 14934, 
14203, 14934, 14934, 14204, 14935, 14935, 14935, 14935, 12744, 
14936, 14936, 14936, 14936, 16398, 11284, 16398, 16398, 16398, 
11285, 14938, 16764, 14938, 12381, 16400, 16400, 12747, 12382, 
14208, 14209, 11287, 14209, 16401, 13844, 16402, 15671, 14210, 
16402, 12749, 12750, 13846, 16403, 16403, 14211, 15673, 15673, 
16404, 11656, 16404, 17135, 17135, 16405, 16405, 17135, 14580, 
16771, 12753, 12388, 14580, 13485, 17137, 14581, 14581, 12389, 
16773, 16773, 15677, 13486, 11294, 12391, 16044, 14217, 14217, 
13122, 12757, 13853, 14218, 17140, 14949, 16776, 17141, 17141, 
16046, 14950, 15681, 12759, 15681, 16412, 12759, 14587, 13126, 
13126, 16413, 16413, 16414, 16414, 16414, 13492, 16414, 16415, 
15684, 16415, 16415, 16415, 16416, 14224, 16416, 14224, 14590, 
14591, 14956, 12764, 14591, 16052, 14957, 12400, 11304, 11304, 
12765, 14958, 14593, 11305, 16784, 14958, 12402, 12402, 12402, 
12402, 12767, 14960, 14595, 14595, 13134, 16421, 12769, 12404, 
12769, 14230, 14961, 12770, 12770, 12770, 15327, 12770, 14232, 
14963, 12406, 17154, 14232, 17155, 14233, 14233, 17155, 17155, 
17156, 17156, 14234, 17156, 12408, 12774, 17157, 12774, 17157, 
17157, 11314, 12775, 17158, 12775, 12775, 11315, 11315, 11315, 
11315, 11315, 11684, 11684, 13510, 11684, 11684, 13511, 13511, 
13511, 11319, 11685, 11320, 12781, 11320, 13512, 12781, 11321, 
11321, 11321, 11321, 11321, 11322, 11322, 11322, 11322, 11322
), class = "Date"), DOY = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 
27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 
36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 
43, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 
46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 
49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
52, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 
56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 59, 
59, 59, 59, 59, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 62, 62, 
62, 62, 62, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 65, 65, 65, 
65, 65, 66, 66, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 68, 68, 68, 68, 
68, 69, 69, 69, 69, 69, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 71, 71, 71, 71, 71, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 75, 
75, 75, 75, 75, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 78, 78, 
78, 78, 78, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 81, 81, 81, 
81, 81, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 84, 84, 84, 84, 
84, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 
88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 
91, 91, 91, 91, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 94, 94, 
94, 94, 94, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 97, 97, 97, 
97, 97, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 
103, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 105, 
105, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 107, 107, 107, 107, 107, 108, 108, 
108, 108, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, 
111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 
113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 118, 118, 118, 118, 
118, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 121, 121, 
121, 121, 121, 122, 122, 122, 122, 122, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 
124, 124, 124, 124, 124, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 126, 126, 126, 
126, 126, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 129, 
129, 129, 129, 129, 130, 130, 130, 130, 130, 131, 131, 131, 131, 
131, 132, 132, 132, 132, 132, 133, 133, 133, 133, 133, 134, 134, 
134, 134, 134, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 
137, 137, 137, 137, 137, 138, 138, 138, 138, 138, 139, 139, 139, 
139, 139, 140, 140, 140, 140, 140, 141, 141, 141, 141, 141, 143, 
143, 143, 143, 143, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 145, 145, 145, 145, 
145, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 147, 147, 147, 147, 147, 148, 148, 
148, 148, 148, 149, 149, 149, 149, 149, 244, 244, 244, 244, 244, 
245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 246, 246, 246, 246, 246, 247, 247, 247, 
247, 247, 248, 248, 248, 248, 248, 249, 249, 249, 249, 249, 250, 
250, 250, 250, 250, 251, 251, 251, 251, 251, 252, 252, 252, 252, 
252, 253, 253, 253, 253, 253, 254, 254, 254, 254, 254, 255, 255, 
255, 255, 255, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 257, 257, 257, 257, 257, 
258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 259, 259, 259, 259, 259, 260, 260, 260, 
260, 260, 261, 261, 261, 261, 261, 262, 262, 262, 262, 262, 263, 
263, 263, 263, 263, 264, 264, 264, 264, 264, 265, 265, 265, 265, 
265, 266, 266, 266, 266, 266, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 268, 268, 
268, 268, 268, 269, 269, 269, 269, 269, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 
271, 271, 271, 271, 271, 272, 272, 272, 272, 272, 273, 273, 273, 
273, 273, 274, 274, 274, 274, 274, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 276, 
276, 276, 276, 276, 277, 277, 277, 277, 277, 278, 278, 278, 278, 
278, 279, 279, 279, 279, 279, 280, 280, 280, 280, 280, 281, 281, 
281, 281, 281, 282, 282, 282, 282, 282, 283, 283, 283, 283, 283, 
284, 284, 284, 284, 284, 285, 285, 285, 285, 285, 286, 286, 286, 
286, 286, 287, 287, 287, 287, 287, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 289, 
289, 289, 289, 289, 290, 290, 290, 290, 290, 291, 291, 291, 291, 
291, 292, 292, 292, 292, 292, 293, 293, 293, 293, 293, 294, 294, 
294, 294, 294, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 296, 296, 296, 296, 296, 
297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 298, 298, 298, 298, 298, 299, 299, 299, 
299, 299, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 301, 301, 301, 301, 301, 302, 
302, 302, 302, 302, 303, 303, 303, 303, 303, 304, 304, 304, 304, 
304, 305, 305, 305, 305, 305, 306, 306, 306, 306, 306, 307, 307, 
307, 307, 307, 308, 308, 308, 308, 308, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 
310, 310, 310, 310, 310, 311, 311, 311, 311, 311, 312, 312, 312, 
312, 312, 313, 313, 313, 313, 313, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 315, 
315, 315, 315, 315, 316, 316, 316, 316, 316, 317, 317, 317, 317, 
317, 318, 318, 318, 318, 318, 319, 319, 319, 319, 319, 320, 320, 
320, 320, 320, 321, 321, 321, 321, 321, 322, 322, 322, 322, 322, 
323, 323, 323, 323, 323, 324, 324, 324, 324, 324, 325, 325, 325, 
325, 325, 326, 326, 326, 326, 326, 327, 327, 327, 327, 327, 328, 
328, 328, 328, 328, 329, 329, 329, 329, 329, 330, 330, 330, 330, 
330, 331, 331, 331, 331, 331, 332, 332, 332, 332, 332, 333, 333, 
333, 333, 333, 334, 334, 334, 334, 334, 335, 335, 335, 335, 335, 
336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 337, 337, 337, 337, 337, 338, 338, 338, 
338, 338, 339, 339, 339, 339, 339, 340, 340, 340, 340, 340, 341, 
341, 341, 341, 341, 342, 342, 342, 342, 342, 343, 343, 343, 343, 
343, 344, 344, 344, 344, 344, 345, 345, 345, 345, 345, 346, 346, 
346, 346, 346, 347, 347, 347, 347, 347, 348, 348, 348, 348, 348, 
349, 349, 349, 349, 349, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 351, 351, 351, 
351, 351, 352, 352, 352, 352, 352, 353, 353, 353, 353, 353, 354, 
354, 354, 354, 354, 355, 355, 355, 355, 355, 356, 356, 356, 356, 
356, 357, 357, 357, 357, 357, 358, 358, 358, 358, 358, 359, 359, 
359, 359, 359, 362, 362, 362, 362, 362, 363, 363, 363, 363, 363, 
364, 364, 364, 364, 364, 365, 365, 365, 365, 365, 366, 366, 366, 
366, 366)), row.names = c(NA, -1345L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(DOY = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 
68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 
84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 
100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 
113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 
126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 
139, 140, 141, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 244, 245, 246, 
247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 
260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 
273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 
286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 
299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 
312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 
325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 
338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 
351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 362, 363, 364, 365, 
366), .rows = list(1:5, 6:10, 11:15, 16:20, 21:25, 26:30, 31:35, 
    36:40, 41:45, 46:50, 51:55, 56:60, 61:65, 66:70, 71:75, 76:80, 
    81:85, 86:90, 91:95, 96:100, 101:105, 106:110, 111:115, 116:120, 
    121:125, 126:130, 131:135, 136:140, 141:145, 146:150, 151:155, 
    156:160, 161:165, 166:170, 171:175, 176:180, 181:185, 186:190, 
    191:195, 196:200, 201:205, 206:210, 211:215, 216:220, 221:225, 
    226:230, 231:235, 236:240, 241:245, 246:250, 251:255, 256:260, 
    261:265, 266:270, 271:275, 276:280, 281:285, 286:290, 291:295, 
    296:300, 301:305, 306:310, 311:315, 316:320, 321:325, 326:330, 
    331:335, 336:340, 341:345, 346:350, 351:355, 356:360, 361:365, 
    366:370, 371:375, 376:380, 381:385, 386:390, 391:395, 396:400, 
    401:405, 406:410, 411:415, 416:420, 421:425, 426:430, 431:435, 
    436:440, 441:445, 446:450, 451:455, 456:460, 461:465, 466:470, 
    471:475, 476:480, 481:485, 486:490, 491:495, 496:500, 501:505, 
    506:510, 511:515, 516:520, 521:525, 526:530, 531:535, 536:540, 
    541:545, 546:550, 551:555, 556:560, 561:565, 566:570, 571:575, 
    576:580, 581:585, 586:590, 591:595, 596:600, 601:605, 606:610, 
    611:615, 616:620, 621:625, 626:630, 631:635, 636:640, 641:645, 
    646:650, 651:655, 656:660, 661:665, 666:670, 671:675, 676:680, 
    681:685, 686:690, 691:695, 696:700, 701:705, 706:710, 711:715, 
    716:720, 721:725, 726:730, 731:735, 736:740, 741:745, 746:750, 
    751:755, 756:760, 761:765, 766:770, 771:775, 776:780, 781:785, 
    786:790, 791:795, 796:800, 801:805, 806:810, 811:815, 816:820, 
    821:825, 826:830, 831:835, 836:840, 841:845, 846:850, 851:855, 
    856:860, 861:865, 866:870, 871:875, 876:880, 881:885, 886:890, 
    891:895, 896:900, 901:905, 906:910, 911:915, 916:920, 921:925, 
    926:930, 931:935, 936:940, 941:945, 946:950, 951:955, 956:960, 
    961:965, 966:970, 971:975, 976:980, 981:985, 986:990, 991:995, 
    996:1000, 1001:1005, 1006:1010, 1011:1015, 1016:1020, 1021:1025, 
    1026:1030, 1031:1035, 1036:1040, 1041:1045, 1046:1050, 1051:1055, 
    1056:1060, 1061:1065, 1066:1070, 1071:1075, 1076:1080, 1081:1085, 
    1086:1090, 1091:1095, 1096:1100, 1101:1105, 1106:1110, 1111:1115, 
    1116:1120, 1121:1125, 1126:1130, 1131:1135, 1136:1140, 1141:1145, 
    1146:1150, 1151:1155, 1156:1160, 1161:1165, 1166:1170, 1171:1175, 
    1176:1180, 1181:1185, 1186:1190, 1191:1195, 1196:1200, 1201:1205, 
    1206:1210, 1211:1215, 1216:1220, 1221:1225, 1226:1230, 1231:1235, 
    1236:1240, 1241:1245, 1246:1250, 1251:1255, 1256:1260, 1261:1265, 
    1266:1270, 1271:1275, 1276:1280, 1281:1285, 1286:1290, 1291:1295, 
    1296:1300, 1301:1305, 1306:1310, 1311:1315, 1316:1320, 1321:1325, 
    1326:1330, 1331:1335, 1336:1340, 1341:1345)), row.names = c(NA, 
-269L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: I don't know what "seasonally appropriate" could mean in this context. Do you a want day-of-year of 1 to reflect September 1?

Comment: I want a DOY of 1 to reflect July 19th (usually DOY of 200). What this would do remove the gap between the distribution humps in the above figure.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Seasonality means a pattern inside the data which follows a seasonal path. But in your data set, there is no value except the time. So how can you expect to detect and model the seasonality with this data? Did you mean dummy variable wrt the day of year instead?

Comment: Thanks for the response @maydin. I didn't include all the dataset as it is rather large. Instead I've only included the relevant parts of the data for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample data you gave was not very illustrative, since it contained one instance each of the same day each year. We'll create some data that is perhaps more representative:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(69)

dates <- as.Date("2015-01-01") + 
          lubridate::days(round(rnorm(5000, 0, 30))) +
          lubridate::years(sample(0:5, 5000, TRUE))

df <- data.frame(Date = dates, DOY = lubridate::yday(dates))

ggplot(df, aes(DOY)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

The way to get rid of this gap is simply to add 6 months and take the result modulo 366:

```r
ggplot(df, aes((DOY + 183) %% 366)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
  lims(x = c(0, 366)) +
  labs(x = "DOY")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>